# GAS reverting cell values back to original if another user is not the authorized user

Tags: google-apps-script

I have tried a few things and you can see my mess of a code below, but I am trying to do the following:

I have a script that logs the current users email into the 1,1 cell of a hidden sheet.  if someone comes in while that person is logged onto the sheet, I am trying to prevent them from editing anyhting.  ( I tried the lock function, but it just functions as a shell script and does not actually lock the google sheet from editing multiple users at once).  so this was my work around.   right now, I got this code to function, but now it keeps giving me errors and failed exicutions because of the e.range and e.value callouts.  any advice on how to make this work?

End goal summary:  I want a user to be able to lock the sheet and if anyone tries to edit it, not be able to change anything while that user is still logged into the sheet.

Thank you!

```
function onEdit(e){
  //var modified = e.range;
  //var newValue = e.value;
  var documentProperties =     PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  var userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var keys = documentProperties.getKeys();
  Logger.log(keys.length);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1LoQdcFZ1zUe-GeJtvcIc7_Dm7ZMwzld-CV0HyFxZaD4').getSheetByName('User');
  var cell = sheet.getRange(1,1).getValue();
  Logger.log(cell);
  Logger.log(userEmail);

  if(cell != userEmail){
    var modified = e.range;
    var newValue = e.value;
    //modified.setValue(e.oldValue);
    e.range.setValue(e.oldValue);
    showAlert("File currently locked by "+cell);

}
}
```

I tried to use the lock feature, but this did not lock it.  so i tried this onEdit function and I keep getting errors.

Comment: LockService requires permissions and onEdit can't perform functions that require permissions.